# Create a dynamic rewrite rule for custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I had created a custom taxonomy named food items. I did that using the CPT UI plugin for WordPress. I wanted to change the rewrite URL to work according to taxonomy terms, not the taxonomy itself

For example:

I have a custom taxonomy named Food attached to custom post type food.

The URL now being formed for the archive is

```
example.com/food_item/bread
```

I wanted it to be like

```
example.com/bread
```

I was able to do that using

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^bread/?$', // the rule regex
    'index.php?taxonomy=food_item&term=bread', // where you want the rule to go
    'top' // the priority. Make this one go first
);
```

But this is not a dynamic solution. There can be more values apart from bread in the future and I don't want to define rules for all of them manually. Is there any solution that this works on any taxonomy with having any terms? Both could be dynamic?

Comment: Any help on this ?

Comment: you can make changes for this from permalink options with category base

Comment: Okay . But would that not apply to all other permalinks as well ? I wanted it only for taxonomy

Comment: http://cnpagency.com/blog/the-right-way-to-do-wordpress-custom-taxonomy-rewrites/  have you created  custom post type in this way here you can pass rewrite rule register  texonomy

Comment: I had seen this link. I have used CUSTOM POST TYPE UI plugin for creating it. I am sure it’s created the right way.

Comment: have you tried to play with Custom Query Var String  and  Custom Rewrite Slug in  CPT UI plugin  Also  Rewrite Hierarchical  if enable or not for parent child relation if needed

Comment: That would be then static . We can use any word we want there as a slug. But I want terms slug to be url instead of taxonomy/term as I mentioned in post

Comment: But  default functionality  work with default term name like this  termname/postname with  post name permalink

Comment: I am not able to get your point here. In custom post type ui . There is no option to make it dynamic. That’s why I had made the above code which works fine but I seeking for a dynamic solution . Anyway to make this dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    function na_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'food_item' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link; }

    add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'na_remove_slug', 10, 3 );
function na_parse_request( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'food_item', 'events', 'page' ) );
    }
}add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'na_parse_request' );
```

you can try this way need to update permalink once after  adding code

Comment: thank you for your answer. I did try this. But it is not working. When i write example.com/bread it should have worked

Comment: You need to update permalinks from setting and after that it will work

Comment: I did try that. But even after that it did not work and opened home page

Comment: I think there must be other issue i have checked code on my local and its working fine  here food_item  i have  used for post type not term have you checked that