# Show custom post archive when custom post not specified

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called `produce` set up in WordPress and a custom taxonomy called `produce_category`.

The URL format for posts in this custom post type is in this format `http://mywebsite/produce/%produce_category%/%postname%/`. Of course `%produce_category%` and `%postname%` get substituted accordingly, a working example url would be `http://mywebsite/produce/fruits-and-vegetables/avocado`.

What I would like to do is show the produce_category custom taxonomy archive if a user visits `http://mywebsite/produce/%produce_category%`, without specifying post name at the end, e.g `http://mywebsite/produce/fruits-and-vegetables` to show all produce in fruits-and-vegetables produce_category.

Besides that when a user visits `http://mywebsite/produce/` I would like to show all the produce archive. EDIT: I have this working now.

I know how to create the archive pages totally fine and have no problem with that. I am stuck at creating permalinks. When I visit `http://mywebsite/produce/%produce_category%` I get a 404 error.

I'm looking for advise on the best way to implement this. Currently I am using **Custom Post Type Permalinks** and **CPTUI**.

The CPTUI custom taxonomy settings interface does not allow me to have a blank in the custom rewrite slug. It defaults to the custom taxonomy slug, `produce_category`, when I don't fill in anything. 
[image]

This gives the front-side produce_category taxonomy archive url as `http://mywebsite/produce/produce_category/%produce_category%/` e.g. `http://mywebsite/produce/produce_category/fish-and-seafood/` when what I want for the archive is `http://mywebsite/produce/fish-and-seafood/`.

Please help with suggestion on the best way I can achieve the custom taxonomy url.

Thank you all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59482836/create-a-dynamic-rewrite-rule-for-custom-taxonomy?noredirect=1#comment105145498_59482836

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It will help you to achieve your url structure... Make sure you update permalinks after saving it to functions.php

```
function custom_produce_category_link( $link, $term, $taxonomy )
{
    if ( $taxonomy !== 'produce_category' )
        return $link;

    return str_replace( 'produce_category/', '', $link );
}
add_filter( 'term_link', 'custom_produce_category_link', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks @Hritik I have tried that code in my functions.php I then went to permalink settings and saved but now the custom taxonomy archives return 404. What do you think could cause this? Thanks.

Comment: Hey @KhaKali, I have found this working on my backend so make sure you have flushed the cache after saving permalink and then go to backend and visit the taxonomy page. I hope it would help !!